# How can I get the index of a match in a MatchCollection?

Tags: c#, regex

Example:

```
Regex inBrackets = new Regex(@"\{(.*?)\}");
String url = "foo/bar/{name}/{id}"; 
MatchCollection bracketMatches = inBrackets.Matches(url); 
int indexOfId = bracketMatches.IndexOf("name"); // equals 0 if IndexOf was a real method
int indexOfId = bracketMatches.IndexOf("id"); // equals 1 if IndexOf was a real method
```

I'm looking at the documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx and don't see any useful methods apart from converting my match collection to an array.

Comment: what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why use Regex for this simple string when it is much easier to use the String.Split() method which gives and index : String[] results = url.Split(new char[] {'/'});

Comment: Right, there's no such method. You will need to pull the matches out into a collection with more functionality.

Comment: @jdweng This was just an example. In my particular use case I do need a MatchCollection of bracket enclosed wildcards.

Comment: This look suspiciously like an MVC route.

Comment: http://ideone.com/233tpJ

Comment: What you want to do is ambiguous. You need a more complicated regex because your current one doesn't contain enough information. Maybe have one named capture group that matches against "brackets that contain only numbers" -- *that* match you could assume is the `id` (and you name the group, "id"), then another group matches "brackets that contain only letters and spaces" you can assume is the `name` field. Or you *assume* that `name` is always the first pair of brackets, `id` is always the second, and validate that there's exactly 2 matches (and hopefully regex is always in order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MatchCollection` can contain multiple matches, it makes no sense to get the index from a collection that could contain 0, 1, or many matches.

You'll want to iterate over each `Match` in the `MatchCollection` like this

```
foreach (Match match in bracketMatches){
    // Use match.Index to get the index of the current match
    // match.Value will contain the capturing group, "foo", "bar", etc
}
```